# How to read a file line by line with Java Stream

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to read a long file line by line and trying in the same time to extract some information from the line.

Here in an example of what i'm doing:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ReadFile_Files_Lines {

    public static void main(String[] pArgs) throws IOException {
        String fileName = "c:\\temp\\sample-1GB.txt";
        File file = new File(fileName);

        try (Stream<String> linesStream = Files.lines(file.toPath())) {
            linesStream.forEach(line -> {
                System.out.println(line);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

One line in my file is devided into three part :

```
10 1010101 15
```

I'm looking to read those three informations every time.
Like :

```
String str1 = line[0];
String str2 = line[1];
String str3 = line[2];
```

The solution i'm looking for will be better if i should not convert the stream to a collection.
I will use those 3 String to create a graph data structure, something like :

```
createGraphe(str1,str2,str3);`
```

I know that i can send the full String, but as i'm learning Stream I'm interested to know how to extract those informations.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. What do you want to do with the three elements? Don't store it if you don't want to

Comment: What about `Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("c:\\temp\\sample-1GB.txt"))` combined with `String.split(" ");` for the values of a single line?

Comment: @deHaar This will have an impact of loading the full file content into memory.

Comment: @user7 I know... Maybe it is not that much... ;-) The word *long* is not really specific. But yes, there may be far better ideas.

Comment: @deHaar From the filename, I'd guess about 1GB ;)

Comment: The lines method you are using in your code already does what you are expecting.

Comment: Also `Stream linesStream` must be `Stream<String> linesStream`

Comment: @user7 for example i want to use those three values to create another String str4.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi no, it dosen't. it only print the line. i'm willing to extract those 3 information.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can map to an array by splitting each line, then call the method you want.

```
Files.lines(filePath)
    .map(l -> l.split(" "))
    .forEach(a -> createGraphe(a[0], a[1], a[2]));
```

Comment: Thank you. it's what i was looking, the spilt methd. can you please confirm that this solution is better than converting the stream to a Collection of String.

Comment: @zakzak That depends on how your graph creation function looks like, but I guess it's better since it doesn't have to store the intermediate `String`.

Answer (score 7):

The method `lines()` you are using already does what you expect it to do.

Java 8 has added a new method called `lines()` in Files class which can be used to read a file line by line in Java. The beauty of this method is that it reads all lines from a file as Stream of String, which is populated lazily as the stream is consumed. So, if you have a huge file and you only read first 100 lines then rest of the lines will not be loaded into memory, which results in better performance.

This is slightly different than `Files.readAllLines()` method (which reads all lines into a List) because this method reads the file lazily, only when a terminal operation is called on Stream e.g. `forEach()`, `count()` etc. By using `count()` method you can actually count a number of lines in files or number of empty lines by filtering empty lines.

Reference: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/07/3-ways-to-read-file-line-by-line-in.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to solve this problem and want to learn how streams can be useful in this situation

1. **Reading a file(Using Java8) , this will fetch you all the lines in the file**: Stream lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath))
2. **Reading this file line by line** : lines.map(line -> line.split(pattern)) , by splitting the line and you will get three sections from the line
3. **Passing the arguments obtained into the functio**n : forEach(arg -> createGraphe(arg[0], arg[1], arg[2]);

I hope this is pretty elaborate for your answer if you want to achieve this